# Run angullar project located in another path than C:\Program Files\nodejs (powershel)

Tags: angular, powershell, command

I have an angular project in this path 
    "C:\GitSuperFood\supafoo\mockup\V1\demoSuper"
    I want to run ng serve  to run the angular project mentioned on the path 
    above 
     when i open power shell command on  this path 
    "C:\GitSuperFood\supafoo\mockup\V1\demoSuper" and run "ng serve"
    I get  this Error

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from 
"C:\\GitSuperFood\\supafoo\\mockup\\V1\\demoSuper".
 Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from 
 "C:\\GitSuperFood\\supafoo\\mockup\\V1\\demoSuper".
at Object.resolve (C:\Users\עילי 
ושקד\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular- 
  devkit\core\node\resolve.js:151:11)
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\עילי 


  ושקד\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular- 
 devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:31:40)
at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\עילי 
  ושקד\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect- 
 command.js:135:55)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Before runing the ng serve command i did the following steps

- 1-installed nodejs located in "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
- 2-installed typescript
- 3-  installed Angular CLI: 8.0.2

any advise?

Comment: did you run `npm install` inside the project directory?

Comment: thanks a lot that helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the angular dependencies if you clone the project from github by running `npm install` or it's shorthand `npm i`

when you are uploading the project to GitHub for optimization you only share `package.json` and `package-lock.json` as reference to your dependencies but you leave the actual node_modules directory from being pushed to your github repo

that's why you need to run npm to tell npm to generate the node_modules folder from the package.json and package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Is a good hint that it's missing in your node_modules folder of your project.
Effectively, as Robert mentionned run

```
npm install
```

in your project folder @ C:\GitSuperFood\supafoo\mockup\V1\demoSuper